# "Life is where my heart is" - Has "where" been used at the right place here?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammar, syntactic-analysis

Here is the sentence - "Life is where my heart is."

Has "where" been used at the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.

"Life is where my heart is..."
"Life is everywhere."
"Life is at home."

Where the heart is, is simply denoting a place or state of matter and hence the entire phrase is acting as an object.

Comment: With an embedded question predicate complement clause _where my heart is_.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your sentence is fine:

> *"Life is [where my heart is]."*

Your sentence involves a fused relative construction. (Usually, a fused relative is a type of noun phrase.) In your sentence, the "where" word is doing double duty: it has a role in the matrix clause "Life is [where]", and at the same time it has a role in an integrated relative clause "[where] my heart is __".

We can see these two functions more clearly if we look at a paraphrase. The following paraphrase involves a noun and integrated relative clause:

- "Life is [at *the place where my heart is*]."

The above *italics* is a noun phrase, which includes the noun "place" and its modifying relative clause "where my heart is".

(Though, note that for this paraphrase, it seems that the noun and integrated relative clause combo happen to be the complement of the preposition phrase headed by "at". This is because the relative word "where" is a preposition.)

Here is a related example from the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, on page 1078:

> The prepositions *when, where, while* . . .
>
> - [30.ii.] *We must put it [where no one will be able to see it].*
>
> . . . These have paraphrases containing noun + integrated relative: . . . *We must put it in a place where no one will be able to see it;* . . .

Answer (score 0):

> > "HOME IS WHERE THE HEART IS"
> >
> > -Pliny the Elder, according to Wikipedia